# Windows Firewall's Advanced Security mode has gone in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-firewall

With Windows 7, I was comfortable with the `Advanced Security` options of Windows Firewall. I could selectively disable specific executables to prevent them accessing the internet.

Now I have upgraded Windows 7 to 8 but I can't find such a control panel entry. I can only find "Enable apps" screen, which could be entirely **replacing** the old control panel but doesn't apparently offer an option to **block** outgoing traffic from an application.

How can I block an executable file or a modern app from accessing internet in Windows 8?

Comment: It doesn't sounds like you're looking at the Control Panel, as it's almost identical to Windows 7.  Did you consider searching for "Firewall"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To block or allow an executable or modern application, go to `Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Firewall`. On the left side of the control panel window, there should be a link that says `"Allow an app or feature through Windows Firewall"`. From there you can edit which applications are allowed through your firewall.

You can also follow the link on the Control Panel page that says `"Advanced settings"`. There you can find and edit all of the Windows Firewall rules.

Comment: Thanks for the advanced settings hint. That's exactly the screen I wanted. I thought it disappeared because in Win7 I used to search it from Start Menu "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security". Anyway for sake of completeness "Allow an app..." option shouldn't be what I want because it allows incoming traffic. I wanted to block outgoing which by default is enabled in a permissive firewall like Windows's firewall

Comment: If you want to get to Windows Firewall from the Start Screen use the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> shortcut key and then type "Windows Firewall"

Answer (score 5):

Advanced Firewall options are still present. Start them this way:

```
"C:\Windows\system32\mmc.exe" "C:\Windows\system32\WF.msc"
```

This is the same MMC snapin like in Windows 7.

Comment: This answer deserves a +1 being correct. However I decided to accept the other: both are equivalent from my point of view

Comment: Isn't only `"C:\Windows\system32\WF.msc"` enough? Anyway, I prefer your answer because I can create a shortcut to it and add to start menu as I used to have on Windows 7, thank you for that.